# Running Python from PHP on one.com

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a python script on one.com after a user completes an action on my website. If I run it using a shell file (every couple of minutes) when I run it in the background and end the ssh session it ends the script. I have tried running if from php using `shell_exec` and `system` but these are blocked by one.com. I was wondering if anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Do you have access to cron?

Comment: No, they also block that

Comment: Then it's time to get a new host.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post i old but for future reference, as I assume you have moved on... I can inform that after I read your question I contacted One.com (12 jan 2016) and they said that they do not support Python and are not planning to do so in the near future.